# Deserializing multiple XML documents into objects with same class names

Tags: c#, xml, oop, xml-parsing

I have a API that I am sending requests to and receiving responses from, to start with I de-serialize a XML request template into a class object, which was just generated by using the paste XML as class option in Visual Studio, then amend the data in a few elements as needed, before serializing back into XML string and sending the request.

When I receive the response, I would also like to de-serialize this as there are a lot of repeated tags, so would be easier to get exact values out by doing:

```
var myvar = Root.Widgets.Widget1.WidgetPrices.PriceInPounds.value
```

The issue is if I get the XML response and paste it as a class object, I then have two classes with the same name because both the Request and Response share some but not all of the same structure, i.e both will contain Root.Widgets. And if I change any of the class object names, then the XML won't de-serialize properly into it. I'm not sure how to get around this so any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a Controller to handle the request/response?  The Controller automatically call the standard XML serialize/deserialize when sending/receiving.    The controller also has capabilities for custom serialize/deserialize.  What you want to do is to use Xml Linq to create an xml and parse an xml instead of using XmlSerialize methods.

Comment: Why not just use a different c# [namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/namespace) for `Request` and `Response`?  See [Declare namespaces to organize types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/namespaces).

Comment: Thanks @dbc, I feel bit of an idiot because yes having under a different namespace absolutely works, as does having it under its own class, I don't know why but I was under the impression you couldn't nest classes in C#, but just having one overarching class for request and another one for response and doing xmlrequest.Rootnode as my type or xmlresponse.Rootnode for the response works perfectly.